# Simulate user interaction on Android device using a script or API

Tags: android

I want to create a neat video demo for my application. As of now I use the DDMS record option to record the demo while I manually interact with the app.

Problem with this approach is that, I sometimes make mistakes (click on the wrong button, take a long pause to think etc). So I end up rerecording or editing the video.

In short the presentation is not as smooth and professional looking as I would like it to be.
I would rather program the touch co-ordinates, delays etc into some script and have it simulate user interaction.

I need to simulate only the standard screen interactions (touch, drag, tap, double tap, pinch, two finger drag etc).

Is there a script, API or tool to do this?

Answer (score 3):

`Robotium makes it easy to write powerful and robust automatic black-box UI tests for Android applications. With the support of Robotium, test case developers can write function, system and user acceptance test scenarios, spanning multiple Android activities.`

I guess Robotium is what you need. What you are doing is sort of like black-box testing.